# How to reshape data frame, header value to column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataset similar to the following structure

```
date        Obj A       Obj B       Obj C
12/12/2001      2       3            4
11/12/2001      5       7            6
```

And I want to reshape them into following structure, for panel plot in ggplot2

```
date        value       factor
12/12/2001      2       Obj A
11/12/2001      5       Obj A
12/12/2001      3       Obj B
11/12/2001      7       Obj B
12/12/2001      4       Obj C
11/12/2001      6       Obj C
```

Is there an easier way/package to do this other than subsetting data and then rbind data one by one?
Thanks for help

Comment: See the `reshape2 (melt/cast)` or `tidyr (gather/spread)` packages or just the base function `reshape()`. Search for help for going from "wide" to "tall" format. This is a very common operation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I used melt(data.frame, id = "date") to reshape the data from wide to tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, if the values to be reshaped are not `factor`s, you can also just use `stack`:

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))
#         date values  ind
# 1 12/12/2001      2 ObjA
# 2 11/12/2001      5 ObjA
# 3 12/12/2001      3 ObjB
# 4 11/12/2001      7 ObjB
# 5 12/12/2001      4 ObjC
# 6 11/12/2001      6 ObjC
```

Answer (score 2):

As MrFlick mentioned, this is a common operation in `R`. However, if you are not familiar with `R`, it may be a bit difficult to figure out how to do this. Here, I'd like to leave you an example using the `tidyr` package. Please note that you do not want to have space in column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create your data
mydf <- as_data_frame(list(date = c("12/12/2001", "11/12/2001"),
                           ObjA = c(2, 5),
                           ObjB = c(3, 7),
                           ObjC = c(4, 6)))

# Transform your data. You have your data, names for key and value columns.
# As you see column names except date are in factor, and numbers are in value.

gather(mydf, factor, value, -date)

#        date factor value
#1 12/12/2001   ObjA     2
#2 11/12/2001   ObjA     5
#3 12/12/2001   ObjB     3
#4 11/12/2001   ObjB     7
#5 12/12/2001   ObjC     4
#6 11/12/2001   ObjC     6
```